# Were Ellen Barkin's legs highlighted or enhanced?

Tags: analysis, effects, switch

In 1991's ***Switch***, a tale of a murdered man resurrected as a woman, Ellen Barkin plays the main characters female persona. In this movie, she is incapable of walking in heels, having never done it as a cis-gendered straight male with no cross dressing tendencies.

But one thing that struck me was that her legs seemed very... masculine? Muscular, they seemed muscular,  more so than any fit late 80's early 90s  woman that looks like a *"shit brickhouse"* would have.

So my question is, did they intentionally enhance or highlight the muscles in Ellen Barkin's legs for the movie? To make her seem more like a man, a reoccurring theme in the movie? In order to make Goldie seem like the male main character Steve?

Answer (score 6):

I am quite certain it is just her legs. She "walked like a man<sup>1</sup>" which would most like cause her to walk different. The fact that she is seen in a skirt throughout most of the movie just accentuates her legs.

There doesn't appear to be a lot of special make-up effects, other than basic make-up, costumes, and the like. This is just a man that got put into a woman's body, not much more magic to it than the cast, the costumes, and the script.

---

Here is a picture of her legs in *Bad Company*, a different movie than *Switch*:

[image: male character looking at a woman on a bed]

<sup>As you can see her legs show some definition.</sup>

Here is a picture of her legs in *Switch*:

[image: Woman standing, wearing a red dress]

<sup>Actually, there appears to be less definition in her legs. That may be what you are attributing to be as more manly.</sup>

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>[Not Your Average Male](https://veniceelisaleonelli.wordpress.com/2015/04/03/ellen-barkinblake-edwards-1991/)</sub>